# Why typescript compiler is not inferring generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have this code

```
type Check<F, T> = F extends string
  ? string
  : T

type Func2 = <F extends T[] | string, T>(functor: F) => Check<F, T>

const x: Func2 = (x: any) => x[0]

const y = x([1, 2])
const z = x("abc")
```

I am getting type `unknown` for `y` while it is perfectly fine for `z`.

The type inferred for calling `x` for `y` is -

```
const x: <number[], unknown>(functor: number[]) => unknown
```

Why there is `unknown` for `T` but `T[]` is inferred properly?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawDwDEA0UAqA+KAXinSggA9gIA7AEwGcp7gAnAS2oHMAoKKAfiasOPPgC5c3bqEgkArtUQAmIlAxlKNBrgDaAXSgAfIey7Z8ACgBmCxMAD2LCegCURAvCRosuPFMT21MxQ5M62KsQWoVAAhtQgboQE5DoADHr+gcEgquQWOgCM2Ep6LtwBQcBQAF65FgBEMQBGiPUuQA)

Comment: There's no inference site for `T` in the signature of `x`.  `F` can be inferred by the type of `functor`, but nothing you're passing in will fix `T` so it falls back to `unknown`.   And so `F` is only constrained to `unknown[] | string`.   I'm not sure why you'd prefer your definition of `Func2` over something like `type Func2 = <F extends { [k: number]: any }>(functor: F) => F[0]`.  Can you explain what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it this way?

Comment: @jcalz The actual code contains other types as well. Check [this](https://github.com/Jozty/Fae/blob/master/nth.ts) for the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does this happen?

Type inference in TS doesn't work as you expect. Type variables could be inferred as I think in three ways:

- based on an argument of a function that has been passed;
- based on analysis of return value of a function;
- based on previously inferred type variables (this rule applied only from left to right order);

That's why you have got `unknown` type.

---

Solution in your case could be:

```
type Check<F, T> = F extends (infer U)[]
  ? U
  : T

type Func2 = <F extends any[] | string>(functor: F) => Check<F, string>

const x: Func2 = (x: any) => x[0]

const y = x([1, 2])
const z = x("abc")
```

Comment: Thank you @Николай Гольцев The solution did work for me. But the inferred signature is correct `const x: <number[], unknown>(functor: number[]) => unknown`. Please check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawDwDEA0UAqA+KAXinSggA9gIA7AEwGcp7gAnAS2oHMAoKKAfiasOPPgC5c3bqEgkArtUQAmIlAxlKNBrgDaAXSgAfIey7Z8ACgBmCxMAD2LCegCURAvCRosuPFMT21MxQ5M62KsQWoVAAhtQgboQE5DoADHr+gcEgquQWOgCM2Ep6LtwBQcBQAF65FgBEMQBGiPUuQA)

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake, you're right! Answer updated.