# Infer does not work in generics as second param

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

does anyone know why in the second case the infer does not display the desired type?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/FAehAIDsHsBMFNwCsDO54Dd6QC7oLYCWOO8ATsAMYA2AhimgKJa6NEnngDew4fBxABQ4AXOBQ4yhSAHMANOAAOY2pACeASm4BfXv2iRB8MRKmyFAMzEAxAK6RKOQga1ddu4PAAei6GTzSpGQWtJSIAEL08MzYOAA8ACpqiojepJCwaKbSMuAAvOKSOQoACrRq1NC0sPngqmoAfNx6fDjJxuBJKXItSuWV1WJlFVWwwB7evv7gbSngMbhd8HELeGnYmeCRKNEsOE0Fq+he6Zvbu7Fx0hacS00A-J3t4CZFsp4+fniziKvDA7BwmololnusMlk3vJ5ntjqc0OdVgcYbE4RsEVFVqDuuBrpx-qMHuACdUXlBMORgB8pt9ngB5SAAGUIEmw5DiJJqBXqyMEin6oyGAuqWjyTQw0EIsAA3FTJl9wDR6Ex2EEVvh2Ks0OCzpi9goGVq0RCtnrYk0ePwlFIMLRSOAyPBqgZqGoBBwyLVIPAAO4o1iq8iCDSyq29eDsIx7MRsTV7FAaMQSqXNK1WnAACxZADoI8QgrnIxTcNmfgpizhs-yRiLQ-xdGGrQYVvHjZtY8QjQAfcCG+MKBJtph7EFahoNKOxMQJBTUFnpchiBnM1nesgt2KcoEgmf+nAoceJ8DJmqWtOtLMoQv58jZgyT3Cz+dssgh3ruKnUhW0ABGplCeBKgw4AAMIGJI0DUNQ7IdjgRo6hiOyrAakDwSc6KmkhexNAh8yBuusFaihY7NOMn4-Hh7BxCBQ6geBZCQdB671AoPLIjRuFgbgDFQeyeKeruPLgI8g5iN6WAUBRDLUbRXEQbxzHqKx6jjrUHHoSack8UxVyQDcnqMAo-G9kSdJkuJlLABRjC1IiexxAARLQDkKAAjE0PZ2ZcDk-i54AAEwNFZ9K2WauCOZQfkAMweZhFzhQ5sB+QALEFVB0MBACCsn0YxMEGhavRkcFcy0LUsFxJlTRgHFWJOX57ngJ5YXxD5fmBbKFE-rU0lVdK4A1V54XZOYdQqUAA)

```
type Emmit<C extends Controller<any, any>> = C extends Controller<infer T, any> ? T : never
type On<C extends Controller<any, any>> = C extends Controller<infer E, infer O> ? O : never

type E = BaseEvent<"a", 1> | BaseEvent<"b", 2>
type O = BaseEvent<"c", 3> | BaseEvent<"d", 4>

class A extends Controller<E, O> {
    
}

type a = Emmit<A> // BaseEvent<"a", 1> | BaseEvent<"b", 2>;
type b = On<A>; // BaseEvent<string, any>
```

Comment: What is `Controller`. Please post the reproducible example with link to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Are the types `BaseEvent`, `EventType`, `EventPayloadByType` defined by you or are they in some library?

Comment: it's mine types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

Extending [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64081790/11642727) answer, the type inference for generics in class is done

- based on properties of the class
- based on type inference from methods.

The type of the first generic is inferred correctly inferred from the parameter of the method `emit` which will be `BaseEvent<"a", 1> | BaseEvent<"b", 2>` in case of class `A`.

But for the second generic, `OnEvent` is used in `on` method only, which is again a generic and will not be inferred until `on` is called. So the TS is not able to  infer the correct type. It is only inferring the constraining type ie `BaseEvent` or `BaseEvent<string, any>`.

Even if you change `on` method to-

```js
on(
  event: EventType<OnEvent>,
  listener: OnListener<EventPayloadByType<EventType<OnEvent>, OnEvent>>
): void {
  this.emitter.on(event, listener);
}
```

it will not infer correctly, as the type information `OnEvent` is not stored as it is but with computed types using `EventType` and `OnListener` which is, I think, out of the capability of TS as of now.

### Possible solution

Best solution that I can think of is adding a dummy property like `private _dummy!: OnEvent`

```js
declare class EventEmitter {
    emit(t: string, p: any): void
    on(e: string, f: Function): void
}

export interface BaseEvent<Type extends string = string, Payload = any> {
    typ: Type,
    payload: Payload
}

export type EventType<Event extends BaseEvent> = Event extends BaseEvent<infer Type>
    ? Type
    : string

export type EventPayloadByType<
    Type extends string,
    Event extends BaseEvent
> =
    Event extends BaseEvent<Type, infer Payload> 
        ? Payload 
        : never

export type OnListener<Payload = any> = (payload: Payload) => void;

export class Emitter<EmmitEvent extends BaseEvent, OnEvent extends BaseEvent> {
    private readonly emitter = new EventEmitter();
    private _dummy!: OnEvent
    //          ^^^^^^ dummy property added here which stores type info for `OnEvent`
    
    emit(event: EmmitEvent): void {
        this.emitter.emit(event.typ, event.payload);
    }
    
    on<Event extends EmmitEvent | OnEvent, T extends EventType<Event>>(
        event: T, 
        listener: OnListener<EventPayloadByType<T, Event>>
    ): void {
        this.emitter.on(event, listener);
    }
}


export abstract class Controller<
    EmmitEvent extends BaseEvent,
    OnEvent extends BaseEvent
> extends Emitter<EmmitEvent, OnEvent> {

}


type Emmit<C extends Controller<any, any>> = C extends Controller<infer T, any> ? T : never
type On<C extends Controller<any, any>> = C extends Controller<any, infer O> ? O : never

type E = BaseEvent<"a", 1> | BaseEvent<"b", 2>
type O = BaseEvent<"c", 3> | BaseEvent<"d", 4>

class A extends Controller<E, O> {
    
}

type a = Emmit<A> // BaseEvent<"a", 1> | BaseEvent<"b", 2>;
type b = On<A>; // BaseEvent<"c", 3> | BaseEvent<"d", 4>
// ^^^^ correctly inferred now

declare const e: A

// type of the argument in emit is `E` ie. BaseEvent<"a", 1> | BaseEvent<"b", 2>
e.emit({typ: "a", payload: 1})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=70&pc=1#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABNGBnViCiA3MA7AF0wFsBLAgsORAb2EQcTDIIAoCAuRVAuUvAOYAaRAAcuMPAE8AlF2wB7UiHqMFeVmC48+gkQDMuAMQCueCAVLq5iRcuABfYMDAAPUQrgFE-SnH0wEEgAQmhgOPgEADwAKlKiSG6UeCAYOvwCiAC83LwZIgAKMFJQCjAg2YiSUgB8tKoMBPFccQlCDWLFpeVcRSVlKk4u7p7eTQlYuIStYFERhEyuyamIoajhUwR1OfPeSfgraxuRUfz6VIgzNR0A-JfxYB3aeYLObh5eiONIu33dIMEpDMoh0ZotlmkXsIOrtwQcMEddsBtjDNnCUgiwrtYg8RGcLn8BnUOoxEHdCeVECTGFw8GBcHA3iNPt9EAB5PAAGVIPHwVCiFIqOWq20QrFEXQGvUl5Rk2TqdhAAG4mR9vCh0FgWH45sQWLD9hjVljNiIOQalvDjetdnU6KTRHxsDBKIgEOV1FApExtRccnSAO6TSIkch+VgyFUOp0upAAfRAJj1UgAhFxzZsOgB6LOkvOIAB6ReLiETybEcAUCS83vK4AqAAsqEgAw3SBAG7lPGAMKyzgpEPpPIgAAYZyIjjodZjkTSbLgkfWbGyK+r5xpt1AAOhnFCoO5Yc8iW-GInpx4l-VlUcYTlJHXUczRhpWi-IsIAPuy8LsRDF0a+mzAraNSsNSDDnoQLQiOBiBQDyyRUOmXIIXycBPpEgqAsCMQiCBHQrkoFT2uuBCbgeYb7uoR6ECI8G8nScCRh0ThDMMapVAARjogTqrAmoAMLqLwChQFA-Iwnq77PpaRqIqaHTjgsL6YjamZ1CpWqUehb5EKa362vUjjOMArK6VEAkARgQmEJWYn8tUIgiqKlmaTZIn2eh+LULhVTSHUdz-rS56MqyHIWVZiDuXZ4noY5fm1C5kXRaJsVRPF3nsgF7KIMFDLOGZlTyScABEMAlSIACMdRfsVhBRCVnEVYgABM1xhUVJqlRAzUAMw1daxz1SVIDNQALNcwAahgACCyXCTF-KYGadpTkMrIwJU5kzXUOaDdiZXNdViC1V1w1NSIbUqqynGVOFO1Koge11dEJU9SI-UnftmwNaNIgTcAe3FgWyCeAgFhej4eDnHACAVHgCgBs44AoAgoN4DwTBcDNzh7ayCj6F8TZVHAAhJpEUM+uQPgYCOmAjj4YBbt9pXlVVA0vQ1F2tdcTO7qwNDjFwh0iJe-xcJVDgyMAQA)

**NOTE**- I have changed some names in the original code

- `BaseEvent.type` to `BaseEvent.typ` (`type` is a keyword in TS, can cause bugs/errors)
- `EmmitEvents` to `EmmitEvent` (it is a type for a single event)
- `OnEvents` to `OnEvent`